# NgModule nested forRoot

Tags: angular, typescript

Considering that there is a module

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({ prefix: 'SOME_PREFIX' }),
        FooModule.forRoot(...),
        BarModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        Ng2Webstorage,
        FooModule,
        BarModule,
    ]
})
class FeatureModule {
    static forRoot(config): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: FeatureModule,
            providers: [...]
        };
    }
}
```

How can it pass `prefix` to `Ng2Webstorage.forRoot` dynamically? Like:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BarModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        Ng2Webstorage,
        FooModule,
        BarModule,
    ]
})
class FeatureModule {
    static forRoot(config): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: FeatureModule,
            imports: [
                Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({ prefix: config.name }),
                FooModule.forRoot(config.foo)
            ],
            providers: [...]
        };
    }
}

...
imports: [FeatureModule.forRoot({ name: `ANOTHER_PREFIX` }), ...]
...
```

Is it possible to have nested `forRoot` calls?

It looks like `ModuleWithProviders` doesn't accept `imports`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right. We can't pass `imports` to `ModuleWithProviders` import.

Here is how angular collects data from such import:

```
} else if (importedType && importedType.ngModule) {
    const moduleWithProviders: ModuleWithProviders = importedType;
    importedModuleType = moduleWithProviders.ngModule;
    if (moduleWithProviders.providers) {
      providers.push(...this._getProvidersMetadata(
          moduleWithProviders.providers, entryComponents,
          `provider for the NgModule '${stringifyType(importedModuleType)}'`, [],
          importedType));
}
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.x/packages/compiler/src/metadata_resolver.ts#L448-L456

We can override provider declated within [Ng2Webstorage.forRoot()](https://github.com/PillowPillow/ng2-webstorage/blob/master/lib/app.ts#L27) by passing the same provider within `ModuleWithProviders.providers` like this:

```
import {Ng2Webstorage, WEBSTORAGE_CONFIG} from 'ngx-webstorage';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    Ng2Webstorage.forRoot()
  ],
  ...
})
export class FeatureModule {
  static forRoot(config): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: FeatureModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: WEBSTORAGE_CONFIG, useValue: config }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was afraid of, it looks like it's the only way. The bad thing here is that forRoot needs dummy config, even if it accepts undefined or empty object now, it can break in future.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by explicitly redefining the providers in `forRoot()`. Other elements of the package can be imported and exported in the usual way.

Note that I use [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to easily chain multiple modules.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BarModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        Ng2Webstorage,
        FooModule,
        BarModule,
    ]
})
class FeatureModule {
    static forRoot(config): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: FeatureModule,
            /* Explicitly redefine the providers from imported/exported modules. */
            providers: [].concat(
                Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({ prefix: config.name }).providers,
                FooModule.forRoot(config.foo).providers
            )
        };
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

The above doesn't work when you use AOT compilation. Instead, use the following workaround with *static exported function* AND *typed argument*, e.g. `config`.

```
export function ng2WebstorageProviders(name: string) {
  return Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({ prefix: name }).providers;
}

export function fooProviders(foo: object) {
  return FooModule.forRoot(foo).providers;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BarModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    Ng2Webstorage,
    FooModule,
    BarModule,
  ]
})
class FeatureModule {
  static forRoot(config: {name: string, foo: object}): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: FeatureModule,
      /* Explicitly redefine the providers from imported/exported modules. */
      providers: [
        ...ng2WebstorageProviders(config.name),
        ...fooProviders(config.foo)
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

For reference:

- [AOT - Function calls are not supported Module.forRoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42427524/aot-function-calls-are-not-supported-module-forroot)
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23609