# Dynamic providers array with forRoot

Tags: angular

I am writting an angular2 **InterceptorModule** which is part of big core project. Every module needs to be fully configurable and independent. All modules are written with `foorRoot` method wchich allow us to achieve global singletons and pass any configuration into it.

We decided to define `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` providers in `forRoot` metod of main module. Thanks to this we have one configuration in one place with all URL rules to fire particular interceptors.

This is simple usage in `import` section of main **AppModule**:

```
CoreInterceptorModule.forRoot([
  {
    instance: TestInterceptor,
    runConditions: [],
  },
  {
    instance: MenuInterceptor,
    runConditions: [InterceptorRunConditions.WhiteList],
    whiteList: ['v1/'],
  },
  {
    instance: MenuInterceptor,
    runConditions: [
      InterceptorRunConditions.WhiteList, 
      InterceptorRunConditions.BlackList
    ],
    whiteList: ['v1/'],
    blackList: ['v1/authorize']
  },
]),

CoreStorageModule.forRoot({
  mode: StorageMode.LocalStorage,
  prefix: 'plCore',
  modesPriority: [StorageMode.SessionStorage, StorageMode.Memory],
}),
```

I have a problem with dynamically injecting providers from `forRoot` section into `ModuleWithProviders` from **CoreInterceptorModule**.

### Working scenario

This is a working solution of injecting `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS`:

```
@NgModule({})
export class CoreInterceptorModule {
  static config(interceptorConfig: IInterceptorConfig[]): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: CoreInterceptorModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG, useValue: interceptorConfig },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: interceptorConfig[0].instance, multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: interceptorConfig[1].instance, multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: interceptorConfig[2].instance, multi: true },
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

Of course this solution is bad because amount of `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` defined in `forRoot` is dynamic.

### Not working scenario

Solution is just to inject providers dynamically, like that:

```
@NgModule({})
export class CwaCoreInterceptorModule {
  static forRoot(interceptorConfig: IInterceptorConfig[]): ModuleWithProviders {

    // base module configuration
    const moduleWithProviders: ModuleWithProviders = {
      ngModule: CwaCoreInterceptorModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG, useValue: interceptorConfig },
      ],
    };

    // update HTTP_INTERCEPTORS array
    interceptorConfig.forEach((e) => {
      moduleWithProviders.providers.push({
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: e.instance, multi: true
      });
    });

    return moduleWithProviders;
  }
}
```

This piece of code causing an exception:

**ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'CoreInterceptorModule'
was called.**

I read some topics about this problem and none of them helped in my case. The problem is that it's not possible to call any function before `return` statement in `forRoot` method.

The question is how dynamically add `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` in `forRoot` method? I thought about something like `useFactory` but it seams it can return just one value (one instance).

Comment: I had similar issue and made a decision to create providers not in shared module but in core module. And just inject them in shared modules with @Inject decorator.

Comment: apparently, this is not supported. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490624/ngmodule-nested-forroot

Comment: @Akanksha Thank you for respond . I tried `useClass` and also additional static/non static helper functions. Not works.
@AlexanderPoshtaruk If there is no any solution I will follow your advice and restructure my concept into similar to yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem. Instead of using my custom configuration type `IInterceptorConfig` (which is later impossible to iterate) I created custom Angular DI provider type inherited from original `Angular\@code\classProvider`:

```
export interface InterceptorClassProvider extends ClassProvider {
  runConditions: InterceptConditions[];
  whiteList?: string[];
  blackList?: string[];
}
```

Thanks to this **I have my additional fields**. `forRoot` method configuration looks like that:

```
CwaCoreInterceptorModule.forRoot([
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: MenuInterceptor,
    multi: true,
    runConditions: [InterceptConditions.WhiteList],
    whiteList: ['/v1']
  },
]),
```

**And finally and the most important I can dynamically fill `ModuleWithProviders` interface in sharedModule without errors**:

```
static forRoot(interceptorProviders: InterceptorClassProvider[]): ModuleWithProviders {
  return {
    ngModule: CwaCoreInterceptorModule,
    providers: [
      { provide: INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG, useValue: interceptorProviders },
      ...interceptorProviders
    ],
  };
}
```

It works because I use array spread operator (`...`) instead of any additional functions call. The only cons of this solution is some unnecessary attributes like `provide`, `useClass`, `multi` which can not be encapsulated in any lower layer.